# Prove that $\cos x $ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

My textbook shows the following solution:

$$|\cos(x) - \cos(c)| \leq \sqrt{(\cos x - \cos c)^2 + (\sin x - \sin c)^2} < |x-c|$$

**The only thing that I don't understand is how to get from the middle to $|x-c|$.**

Is it from geometry?

Comment: the expression in middle is the length of the straight line joining the points $(\cos x,\sin x)$ and $(\cos c,\sin c)$. $|x-c|$ is the length of the arc joining them (when $|x-c| < \pi$) and straight line is the shortest curve joining two points on the plane.

Comment: The inequalities above *can't* be strict unless it is specified that $x\neq c$.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming one knows that, as $u \to 0$,
$$
|\sin u |\le|u|,
$$ then by expanding one easily gets
$$
(\cos(x) - \cos(c))^2 + (\sin(x) - \sin(c))^2=2(1-\cos(x-c))=4\sin^2\left(\frac{x-c}2 \right)
$$ giving
$$
\sqrt{(\cos(x) - \cos(c))^2 + (\sin(x) - \sin(c))^2}\le2\left|\sin\left(\frac{x-c}2 \right)\right|\le2\left|\frac{x-c}2\right|\le|x-c|.
$$